# how to post form data using HttpWebRequest in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

i've seen a lot of examples of using HttpWebRequest to post form data, but unfortunately, i'm having a hard time finding a specific article dealing with this class in WP7. does anyone have a good reference on how to do this?

note, i don't want to upload a file, i just need to issue a "POST" command sending some key/value pairs (e.g. ) . i can't use "GET" to send the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadstringasync(v=vs.95).aspx

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.UploadStringAsync(HostUrl, "POST", "DataYouWantToPost");
```

Comment: NB : its worth setting up fiddler on your dev machine to see what is going on and if the data is being posted correctly

Answer (score 2):

After settings `HttpWebRequest.Method` to `POST`, call `BeginGetRequestStream`. When it completes, `EndGetRequestStream` will return the `Stream` that you can write to.

If you're using Mango, `WebClient` is probably going to be easier. (`WebClient` existed pre-Mango, but was recommended against as it always returned on the UI thread)